# Como esse código restringe a entrada a um número entre 0 e 4?

Tags: c

Estava respondendo esta questão, porém não faz sentido para mim.

[image: Código]

Para mim teria que relacionar valores menores que 0 e maiores que 4. Eu entendi que compreendia o inverso da alternativa C.

Comment: Se você [executar o código](http://ideone.com/KJrBTR) você vai entender melhor. Se você digitar um número maior que 4 ou menor que 0, o programa pede para inserir um numero valido.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A resposta correta é a C.

> O programa calcula o fatorial

Claramente o programa está fazendo isto - *Checked*

> de um valor fornecido no intervalo entre 0 e 4 inclusives (sic)

```
while(n<0 || n>4)
scanf("%d", &n);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/ValidationRange.c).

Este trecho faz justamente isto. Fica repetindo o pedido enquanto um número entre o intervalo definido não for digitado. Quando for digitado algo entre 0 e 4 o código sai do laço e continua a execução calculando o fatorial do número digitado logo à seguir. Este trecho só tem a função de ficar insistindo em um número válido - *Checked*

> não calculando o fatorial para outros valores que não estejam nesse intervalo

Como o código não sai do laço se digitar outros valores, ele não consegue calcular o fatorial para outros valores. - *Checked*

A opção `d` claramente não pode ser porque afirma aceitar o número 5 que é óbvio que não aceita.

A opção `b` só seria possível se tivesse dois laços um dentro do outro, o interno para calcular o fatorial e o externo para variar a sequência numérica.

A opção `a` só seria viável se a `c` estivesse errada também, o que não é o caso.

O código é mal escrito e não parece ensinar nada útil, provavelmente você deve fugir de materiais como este.